# Why this code can't be compiled in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++

```
#include <complex>

using Complex   = std::complex<double>;
using Byte      = unsigned char;

auto operator*( Byte const b, Complex const& c )
    -> Complex
{ return Complex( b )*c; }

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    Byte const      b = 42;
    Complex const   c = {2, 3};         // 2 + 3*i

    cout << b*c << endl;
}
```

[image]

I'm trying compile it on ideone.com and it runs good, but in Visual it doesn't make progress.

Comment: Some of the c++11 features may not be present in 2010.

Comment: Can you please include the error messages in your question, rather than linking to a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

The code uses trailing return types (e.g. `-> Complex`) and `using` aliases, which were added to the language in 2011. A compiler older than that (such as yours from 2010) might well not support them.

Either use a more up-to-date compiler, or change the function headers and type aliases to the old-school style:

```
typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef unsigned char Byte;

Complex operator*( Byte const b, Complex const& c )
int main()
```

If there are still errors, then you'll need to tell us what they are and which lines they come from.

Answer (score 1):

You are using C++11 in visual studio 2010. For c++11 in visual studio, use Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

MS VC++ 2010 does not support many features of the C++ 2011 Standard including the alias declaration.

Use `typedef` declarations instead of alias-declarations. For example

```
typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef unsigned char Byte;
```

Take into acccount that this declaration of main

```
auto main() -> int
```

is invalid even in the C++ 2011 Standard. It is allowed only in C++ 2014 Standard. So it would be better and more readable if you would declare main as usual

```
int main()
```

There is no any reason to declare main as

```
auto main() -> int
```

It is simply a bad style of programming.

Also standard class complex has non-member operator *. For example

```
template<class T> complex<T> operator*(const complex<T>& lhs, const T& rhs);
template<class T> complex<T> operator*(const T& lhs, const complex<T>& rhs);
```